# Ruby on Rails - ActiveAdmin Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i followed a Youtube Video to implement ActiveAdmin Theme in my Rails App,- and everything worked like a charm (i thought).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2x995hm8r8

I followed every Step he took and i am a little confused right now because i can't create posts.
Whenever i try to create a New Post and type in the tile, body and select a image- it just won't do anything. It doesn't even give me a Error Message.

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostController < ApplicationController

def index
    @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(4).offset(1)
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end


private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end

end

ActiveAdmin.register Post do
```

posts.rb

```
permit_params :title, :body, :image

show do |t|
    attributes_table do
        row :title
        row :body
        row :image do
            post.image? ? image_tag(post.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "No image yet")
        end
    end
end

form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
    f.inputs do
    f.input :title
    f.input :body
    f.input :image, hint: f.post.image? ? image_tag(post.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "Upload JPG/PNG/GIF image")
end
f.actions
end
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140}

has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/


end
```

EDIT I:

`Started POST "/admin/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-20 14:30:24 +0100
    Processing by Admin::PostsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"f+hfBD3lzgXEfz1q38/i3YciHsbb5LYWbbHUUsyIeOCaNSUReUUVVTBE//Dw0zXxSuFCzcMfYuUGDtIJlNb58w==", "post"=>{"title"=>"asdasdasd", "body"=>"asdasdasd"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering /Users/useruser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-2cf85fb03ab3/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb
  Rendered /Users/useruser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-2cf85fb03ab3/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (134.6ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 230ms (Views: 148.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)`

If you need more of my Code just tell me what i should post in here.
I am just getting started with Ruby on Rails and Programming overall, so yes indeed, i am a Newb.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `@post.save!` (Notice "!") in your `create` action.

Comment: That doesn't work either...

Comment: What do you see? Paste your request logs in question.

Comment: Im sorry but how do i see my request logs?

Comment: in your terminal you should see output as you make requests in your browser

Comment: also in your code example, what is `posts.rb` ? Console output doesn't show an error so must be something in your code.

Comment: posts.rb is the post model for active admin - app/admin/posts.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your edit 1, I see that you render `new` after submiting form. It means that your Post is not being saved. It also means that your application does exactly what it should do.

I assume that you are using latests Rails 5.

In Post model, you have `belongs_to` association (Post belongs to User).
In Rails 5, that means `user` or `user_id` has to be provided, to create Post (Post cannot belong to noone), else you won't be able to save.

Depending how you created association in table, you might be able to pass `user` or `user_id` in params.

Another way to create post belonging to particular user is:

```
@user = User.first
@post = @user.posts.build(post_params)
```

For ActiveAdmin, you can use default form that is created based on your model.
Just make sure you permit all params when creating it that way

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params %i[title body image user_id]
  ...
end
```

You can also set `belongs_to :user` association as optional.

---

Now some general advices from me:

First of all use proper indentation.

My advice to you is install Rubocop gem.

Second:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(4).offset(1)
end
```

That doesn't make much sense, you overwrite instance variable just after first assignment. 
`@post = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(4).offset(1)` is more of an index action, since it does not show particular posts, it show 2..5 newest posts.

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Misses `image` attribute.

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

You duplicate `params[:post].permit(:title, :body)`. You hgave already created private method for that. Use it here. Same goes for creation action, you duplicated it there too. Read what DRY code is about (google it).

Comment: last part of this answer explains the validation error. Good answer!

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right. My belongs_to is causing this error. I removed it just to test it and it works like a charm.

Comment: As I am constantly editing post to be more readable and you might not see it, I'll repeate here "You can also set `belongs_to :user` association as optional.". I hope you can google that one.

Comment: He is using ActiveAdmin, so the controller code shown is never used to create new records imho.

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right. My belongs_to is causing this error. I removed it just to test it and it works like a charm. (Rails 5 indeed)

In my posts_controller, do i have to set the image attribute to every permit i use in there? (eg. for def update)

With the current_admin_user code and belongs_to :user it has the same effect like i had before, no posts are created.

I've read about Dont Repeat Yourself already, as i mentioned earlier, i am just getting started. :) But i thought i need the `params[:post].permit(:title, :body)` in my update method aswell.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake there.  The way I wrote is normal post creation, when you create is as normal logged in user. In admin panel, you create posts with selecting particular user (you have to add `user` combo box to your form in ActiveAdmin panel).

Comment: No Problem for writing in parts, sir!

About the Rubocop Gem, i installed it and typed rubocop and got 64 files inspected, 434 offenses detected - do i have to change every offense by hand? 

434 offenses look like a lot to me :-'

Comment: These comments are getting offtopic and too long, lets use chat. Ah yeah, I cannot create one as I dont have 100 reputation... Long story short, yeah, you should check every offense. It is a lot, because it detects many anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

You have `belongs_to :user` but never set a `user_id`. A `belongs_to` relation is by default required (in recent rails 4/5), and this will block the saving. The easiest way, for now, to fix this is to write it as following

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

[EDIT: how to store current-user as owner of post]

If you want to automatically set the user to the currently logged in user, which I think is the intention, you can add the following to your active-admin configuration:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  # .. keep your original configuration here ...

  before_build do |record|
    record.user = current_user
  end

end
```

Or add an extra field to the form allowing the administrator to select the user?

Comment: Yes! This works! But for the long view, how am i supposed to do it correct?

Comment: You mean: how to set the user-id automatically from ActiveAdmin I think? I added that part.